# How to embed textview in react-google-maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, textview, react-google-maps

How to embed textview in react-google-maps? I have successfully created a google map page in react using [react-google-maps api](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/). This is how I insert the marker and link the marker using polyline.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  Polyline
} from "react-google-maps";

const pathCoordinates = [
        { lat: 1.322459, lng: 103.853972 },
        { lat: 1.39227, lng: 103.752 }
    ];

const CustomSkinMap = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props => (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={12}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: 1.322459, lng: 103.853972 }}
      defaultOptions={{
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        styles: [
          {
            featureType: "water",
            stylers: [
              { saturation: 43 },
              { lightness: -11 },
              { hue: "#0088ff" }
            ]
          },
          {
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [
              { hue: "#ff0000" },
              { saturation: -100 },
              { lightness: 99 }
            ]
          },
          {
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "geometry.stroke",
            stylers: [{ color: "#808080" }, { lightness: 54 }]
          },
          {
            featureType: "landscape.man_made",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [{ color: "#ece2d9" }]
          },
          {
            featureType: "poi.park",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [{ color: "#ccdca1" }]
          },
          {
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "labels.text.fill",
            stylers: [{ color: "#767676" }]
          },
          {
            featureType: "road",
            elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
            stylers: [{ color: "#ffffff" }]
          },
          { featureType: "poi", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }] },
          {
            featureType: "landscape.natural",
            elementType: "geometry.fill",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }, { color: "#b8cb93" }]
          },
          { featureType: "poi.park", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
          {
            featureType: "poi.sports_complex",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }]
          },
          { featureType: "poi.medical", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }] },
          {
            featureType: "poi.business",
            stylers: [{ visibility: "simplified" }]
          }
        ]
      }}
    >
      <Marker label= {"1"} position={{ lat: 1.322459, lng: 103.853972 }} />
      <Marker label= {"2"} position={{ lat: 1.39227, lng: 103.752 }} />
      <Polyline
                path={pathCoordinates}
                geodesic={true}
                options={{
                    strokeColor: "#ff2527",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.75,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                }}
            />
    </GoogleMap>
  ))
);

function Maps({ ...props }) {
  return (
    <CustomSkinMap
      googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg"
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100vh` }} />}
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    />
  );
}

export default Maps;
```

However,I have no idea how to embed textview inside this google map. I want to add a textview to let user select date then read the data from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just simply create a css file then set z-index as 100 and top:70px right:20px width:220px . Then the textview will display at right corner of the map.